# Why is my page is not getting currently logged in when reload?

Tags: angular, iis, windows-authentication, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

I'm using Angular for my website. Initially once the page is launched, there are no issues and it authenticates perfectly.  However, when refreshing the page it can't pull the currently login user anymore.  It looks like it doesn't call windows authentication. I'm adding my code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log('AppInterceptorService1111');
    req = req.clone({
        withCredentials: true
      });

    return next.handle(req)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

The local storage has already been implemented.

```
this.authenticateCurrentNTLogin().subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.currentUserInfoService.tokenInfo = data.Response;            
            localStorage.setItem('userToken', this.currentUserInfoService.tokenInfo.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem('userRoles', this.currentUserInfoService.tokenInfo.role);        
            this.currentUserInfoService.currentUserTokenExpiration = new Date();
            this.currentUserInfoService.currentUserTokenExpiration.setSeconds(new Date().getSeconds() + parseInt(this.currentUserInfoService.tokenInfo.expires_in));
            localStorage.setItem('myTokenExpiration', this.currentUserInfoService.currentUserTokenExpiration.toLocaleDateString() +
            ' ' + this.currentUserInfoService.currentUserTokenExpiration.toLocaleTimeString());                     
        },
```

Comment: Please type in your sample code and error code. If possible do not post it with a picture. It would make people reluctant to answer your question. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why don't you use local storage for storing and retrieving the user data? Just check out local storage.set() and local storage.get(). So, even after refreshing the data remains in those variables.

Comment: I am thinking that this might be an IIS configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

After logging with authentication, store the user id or login id in a variable. And throughout the application you can retrieve this local variable to confirm if user id logged in or not even after refreshing. When he logs out, clear that variable. In other terms, you can use local storage as session on client side. Use the below one when user logs in and when authenticated true.

```
localStorage.setItem("user", user id)

var user = local storage.getItem("user")
```

In the page that you are reloading, use .get method and if user is not null then allow him to access current page. If user variable is null, then user is not logged in and redirect him to login page.
 When user logs out:

```
local storage.removeItem("user")
```

Hope this was what you were asking about.

Comment: my pages are windows authenticated based on the login name of the user.

Comment: I'm still getting the same issues.

Comment: Can you make your issue clear? Is there any error popping up?  Are you able to store the values in local storage? If so, can you store and retrieve them?

Comment: Is it not getting data from local storage when refreshing page?

Comment: Yes, it is not getting data from local storage after refresh.

Comment: Are you getting before refresh? Call a function and print in console. Check if it's stored. I think it's not stored.

Comment: Yes, i'm getting window authentication before refresh.  After, refresh it's getting the application pool identity instead of window authentication.

Comment: Is it possible to allow window authentication credentials in CORS at Startup.cs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768965/windows-authentication-and-angular-7-application check if this helps

Comment: The reason why I want to force windows authentication in CORS to grab the credentials after reload.

Answer (score 0):

in my apps, once a user authenticates, I store the username & user_id in localStorage, so it has instant access anywhere in the app.

Comment: where can i implement localStorage?

Comment: Implement immediately after server returns that the user is authenticated. Do that in your ts or js file.

Comment: anywhere in any js or ts file. `localStorage.username = data.username; var username = localStorage.username;` easy as that